Enumerate Microsoft Graph API "toRecipients"
I am writing a MS Powerapp that works with emails from a user's Outlook365 mailbox. I can get a list (table) of email information including the "toRecipients" field using the Office365Groups.HttpRequest function. However, this field is an array (an array or collection within an array) and I cannot figure out how to enumerate the toRecipients of each email, in a Gallery for example.
Note: I am using the Graph API because the Office365.GetEmails functions are limited to a max of 25 messages. I have tried using comparison operators such as "in" and even tried the Concat function to reduce the array of "toRecipients" to a single string with delimiters, with no success.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I figured it out by using the Monitor function of Powerapps. It shows the returned data and allows to drill down into the table (where I found the field names).

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
